# If Statement In Bash With Variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, if-statement

I am trying to check if a remote version is greater than a local version with variables and if statements.

But, so far the variables echo the correct version but even if the remote version is greater than a local version nothing happens with the if statement, what am i doing wrong.

Thanks

```
lversion_notepadqq() {
    notepadqq -v
}

rmersion_notepadqq() {
    curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/notepadqq/notepadqq/releases | grep tag_name | cut -d \" -f 4 | grep v| tr -d 'v,' | head -1
}

Remote=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/notepadqq/notepadqq/releases | grep tag_name | cut -d \" -f 4 | grep v| tr -d 'v,' | head -1)
Local=$(notepadqq -v)
echo Local Version: $Local
echo Remote Version: $Remote

if (( rmersion_notepadqq > lversion_notepadqq )); then 
    echo Updating && Update_Notepadqq
else
    echo No Update Needed
fi

#Neither if statement seems to work

if (( $Remote > $Local )); then 
    echo Updating && Update_Notepadqq
else
    echo No Update Needed
fi
```

output:

```
Local Version: Notepadqq 1.4.8
Remote Version: 1.4.0
No Update Needed
./Specific-Updates.sh: line 50: ((: 1.4.0 > Notepadqq 1.4.8 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".4.0 > Notepadqq 1.4.8 ")
No Update Needed
```

Comment: What's the outcome of the `echo` commands? What are `$Local` and `$Remote` variable values?

Comment: `(( rmersion_notepadqq > lversion_notepadqq ))` does not work since `rmersion_notepadqq` and `lversion_notepadqq` are interpreted as variable names. To *call* a function you have to encapsulate it in `$( ... )`.

Comment: Are you sure the script is executed using bash? Add `#! /bin/bash` to the beginning.

Comment: `bash` itself can't meaningfully compare version numbers. You'll need to compare them field by field. For example, to compare `1.3.9` and `1.3.10`, you'll need to perform integer comparisons of `1` vs `1`, `3` vs `3`, and `9` vs `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version tags are strings, you should quote your variables (to avoid syntax errors in limit cases, such as null values).

```
Remote="1.4.0"
Local="1.3.9"

# lexicographic comparison
if [ "$Remote" \> "$Local" ]; then
  echo Updating # && Update_Notepadqq
else
  echo No Update Needed
fi
```

*Note 1: > and < are redirection operators so escape it with \.*

*Note 2: Lexicographic comparison isn't sufficient if you can have tags like 1.3.9 and 1.3.10 (from @chepner comment). If that is the case you should compare each version group separately... See the following update...*

**UPDATE**: To correctly compare versions you should more safely use a function like this:

```
compareVersions() {

  # returns:
  #  - 0 if versions are equal (by the way: 1.4 == 1.4.0)
  #  - 1 if the 1st version is greater
  #  - 2 if the 2nd version is greater

  local v1=( $(echo "$1" | tr '.' ' ') )
  local v2=( $(echo "$2" | tr '.' ' ') )
  local len="$(max "${#v1[*]}" "${#v2[*]}")"
  for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do
    [ "${v1[i]:-0}" -gt "${v2[i]:-0}" ] && return 1
    [ "${v1[i]:-0}" -lt "${v2[i]:-0}" ] && return 2
  done
  return 0
}

result=compareVersions "$Local" "$Remote";
if [ $result -eq 1 ]; then
  echo Updating # && Update_Notepadqq
else
  echo No Update Needed
fi
```

Comment: Not quite, `>`, if supported by `[`, compares the values lexicographically. Using `((...))` will either produce an error (if the tags look like floating-point numbers) or could give a wrong result (if the values are valid identifiers).

Comment: Lexicographic comparison isn't sufficient if you can have tags like `1.3.9` and `1.3.10`.

Comment: @Socowi: Double Parenthesis - (( ... )) is for arithmetic operation

Comment: Also, in general `[` isn't guaranteed to support `>` for string comparison. `bash`'s built-in`[` does, but if you know you are using `bash`, you may as well use `[[ ... > ... ]]` instead.

Comment: Did you *quote* your variables ("$Local"...) ?

Comment: @Socowl: Try this: `(( 5.9 < 5.10 )); echo $?` (syntax error... :-()

Comment: Ah, now I understood what you meant. I assumed the OP's values were only numbers. Thanks chepner for clearing things up.

Comment: @Socowl: no, they are not... See output from `curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/notepadqq/notepadqq/releases | grep tag_name | cut -d \" -f 4 | grep v| tr -d 'v,' | head -1` ...

Comment: Regarding your edit, you could make use of `sort` `-V` option instead of your `for` loop

Comment: @MarcoS Thanks for the answer but, when i use your code i get this error, also i have added `Local="1.3.9"`. `Local Version: 1.3.9
Remote Version: 1.4.0
./Specific-Updates.sh: line 60: 1.3.9: command not found
./Specific-Updates.sh: line 61: [: -eq: unary operator expected
No Update Needed`

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete response, but a better/proper way to fetch version :

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/notepadqq/notepadqq/releases |
    jq -r '[ .[] | select(.tag_name | contains("v")) | .tag_name][0]'
```

### Output :

```
v1.4.0
```

### Note

Don't parse JSON with grep | tr etc... Use the proper parser: [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)